# Angle Bracket Characters in Apple TV2 On Screen Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I've speen a while trying to figure this out to no avail.  On 4.3.1 Apple TV2's Onscreen Keyboard, I can't find some characters, in particular angle brackets (< and >).  I know some characters can be accessed by holding select over the 'master' character, but none of them seem to have < and > in 4.3.  They were present in 4.2 firmware version keyboard, which was of a different design.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have an AppleTV so I'm taking a stab in the dark. What bracketing type of characters does the AppleTV have? Would the angle bracket characters not be under the parenthesis `( )`'s, or right angle brackets `[ ]`'s?

I would expect that there wouldn't be curly brackets `{ }`'s built in, but they might be in the same location.

Comment: I thought of that; and while it does have curly braces, I can't find angle brackets under any of them.  It wasn't under any brackets at all that I saw.

Comment: Seriously? Curly brackets but no Angle Brackets? Scary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There never was a solution I found; but by using an iOS device (ipod Touch, iphone, ipad) and the Remote app, a full ability to type into boxes was enabled and allowed me to work around this problem.